# How to integrate an imaginary exponential to give a Delta function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is there a way to get Mathematica to integrate imaginary exponential functions to give delta functions? Analytically, we obtain:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i kx} dk = 2 \pi \delta(x)$$

Code:

```
Integrate[E^(I k x), {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

However, an error saying that the integral does not converge in these limits stops the integral from being evaluated.

Comment: 2023... It's a pity this still would not work, even upon specifying the `Assumptions` ^_^

Answer (score 4):

For Fourier integrals like this one, use `FourierTransform`.

```
FourierTransform[1, k, x, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}]
(* 2 \[Pi] DiracDelta[x] *)
```

`FourierTransform` understands that it can use generalized functions like `DiracDelta` to represent some integrals that don't converge. `Integrate` can't do that.